# Is it possible to add bootstrap into .net siteMapNode?

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add a bootstrap badge with the number of projects to a siteMapNode configured on my Web.sitemap. Is this possible? Below is what I want but I don't know how to get the results. I have searched and can not find anything specific to this goal.
***deleted other siteMapNodes before and after this one***

```
    <siteMap>
        <siteMapNode>
            <siteMapNode roles="Developer" url="~/app/a.aspx#/MyProjectsQueue" title="My Projects" description="View All My Projects Queue"/>
                <span class='badge badge-gold' uib-tooltip="# of current projects.">{{projects.length}}</span>  
        </siteMapNode>
    </siteMap>
```

Comment: have you looked at any boot-strap tutorials

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being extremely easy and somewhat obvious, just didn't see it. Just used escaped characters to add my html to the xml.

```
<siteMap>
    <siteMapNode>        
        <siteMapNode roles="Developer" url="~/app/a.aspx#/MyProjectsQueue" title="My Projects Queue &lt;span class=&quot;badge badge-error &quot; &gt; {{curUser.OpenProjectsNum}}&lt;/span&gt;" description="View All My Projects Queue" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```